# UFT Results are not visible in Jenkins Report

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, hp-uft

Here some guy posted a problem about UFT reports on Jenkins. He received no responce at all. I have the same problem. Maybe here we will get some help.

https://community.saas.hpe.com/t5/Unified-Functional-Testing/UFT-Results-are-not-visible-in-Jenkins-Report/m-p/233091

"I have a VM where UFT 12.52 and Jenkins Server are running. I can access Jenkins from my local computer and start the job, after the test is finished the results are published, but when I click on "run_results.html" it is an empty webpage (the run_results.xml it has the results but is not very user friendly). If I go on the VM where the Jenkins and UFT are running, and go into the Jenkins build folder and open the run_results.html I can see the results. What is wrong with the results from Jenkins?

Note* If I download the zip from Jenkins with the report, the result are visible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging through the internet, I found that Jenkins has some security policy regarding the HTML/JS files on it workspace.

After setting System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "")
it fixed the issue!

See detailed description here: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuring+Content+Security+Policy

*Update:
since after jenkins restart those setting are reset, for permanent relaxing Content Security Policy (CSP) you should add an argument to java that runs jenkins.war.
Here you can examples and more description about how to do that:
https://kb.froglogic.com/display/KB/Content+Security+Policy+%28CSP%29+for+Web+Report